# React.js and Ant Design: "Element type is invalid" error when rendering child component

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import React from 'react'
import Announcement from '../Components/Announcement.js'
import NavigationBar from '../Components/NavigationBar.js'
import SliderCarousel from '../Components/SliderCarousel.js'

import Categories from '../Components/Categories.js';

function Home() {
    // you can use
    return (
        <>
            <Announcement />
            <NavigationBar />
        

       
            <SliderCarousel />
            
            <Categories />
        
        
        </>
    )
}

export default Home




import React from "react"
import { Card,Grid,Row,Col } from "antd"
import "../projectStyling/Categories.css"
import {categoriesData} from "./categoriesData.js"



function Categories() {
   
    return (

            
                <Grid  key={1}  >
                    <Row className="GridStyling">
                        
                        <Col span={8}>
                            <Card cover={<img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61uxHDdgfxL._UL1440_.jpg' alt='formal '/>}/>
                        </Col>

                        <Col span={8}>
                        <Card cover={<img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61uxHDdgfxL._UL1440_.jpg' alt='formal '/>}/>
                        </Col>
                        
                        <Col span={8}>
                        <Card cover={<img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61uxHDdgfxL._UL1440_.jpg' alt='formal '/>}/>
                        </Col>

                    </Row>
                </Grid>
               
            
                    
    )
}

export default Categories;
```

I'm currently working on a React.js project that incorporates Ant Design components. I have a parent component called Home that renders a child component called Categories. While I believe my code is correct, I've been encountering a "Element type is invalid" error at runtime, and I've been unable to resolve it after two days of debugging.

Despite thorough checking, I can't seem to identify the root cause of this issue. Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this "Element type is invalid" error in my React application? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Grid` is not a component exported from `antd`, removing that will solve your problem. [learn more about how to create Grid](https://ant.design/components/grid)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Grid. Also from import